# Downloading whole Facebook user’s profile page

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to download the whole profile of a user (not mine) with WinHTTRACK or Offline explorer or some other similar tool? I need the settings.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the best tool I have found for website copying is [httrack](http://www.httrack.com/), but it depends on Facebook’s robots.txt which probably won't allow you to copy other people’s profiles using a tool like that.

The specifics of what you need to do to download someone else's page depends on your browser but for example, in Firefox you simply do: *right click* → *Save page as...* and it will save a HTML copy of the page which you can open offline.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to download a whole bunch of pages quickly from a website, I use site sucker:

http://www.sitesucker.us

Is this what you are looking for?

For windows you might want to consider downloading cygwin, and using a command like this to download a website:

```
wget -r http://my.site.to.download.com
```

Comment: So, the website itself doesn't download the pages but an app?

Comment: No, software you mentioned is for OS X.

Comment: What about form login?

Comment: Do you have the credentials?

Comment: But this wouldn't include any content loaded via JavaScript/Ajax.

Comment: Ajax's indeed gonna make it a very difficult task for such tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with saving the page as a PDF, you have at least a couple of options:

- If you use Google Chrome you can [save the entire web page as a PDF](http://www.labnol.org/software/save-web-page-as-pdf/21153/):

> Open any web page inside Google Chrome, press Ctrl+P (or Cmd+P if you
>   are on a Mac) to open the Print dialog and change the destination
>   printer to “Save as PDF.”

- If you're on Mac OS X you can [save almost anything as a PDF](http://osxdaily.com/2010/05/21/how-to-print-to-pdf-in-mac-os/), from the Print dialog in any application: Click *File → Print*, click the *PDF* button and select *Save as PDF*.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a soft copy of a Facebook page, using Print to save an entire Facebook profile as pdf or png gives a mass (for me). The Chrome extensions, such as Screen Capture and Screen Recorder, can do "whole page capture" which works for me. Saw a paid software "Page Vault" which might also work (I haven't tested it).